# How to use @Component decorator in both abstract class and in the implementation of abstract class in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I use Angular 8 & try to use abstract components. I want to define the templateUrl & the styleUrls in my abstract class, but the selector name in the implemented class. Like this:

```js
@Component({
  // selector isn't defined here
  templateUrl: './abstract-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./abstract-list.component.scss']
})
export abstract class AbstractListComponent<T> implements OnInit {
  // ...
}
```

And in the child class

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-custom-list',
  // templateUrl & styleUrls is should be inherited
})
export class MyCustomListComponent extends AbstractListComponent<MyCustomListInterface> implements OnInit {
  // ...
}
```

I tried to use the decorator only in implementation like this, but I feel here need to be a better way:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-custom-list',
  templateUrl: '../../abstract-list/abstract-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../../abstract-list/abstract-list.component.scss']
})
```

Is it possible to use `@Component` decorator something like this? Or is there any trick or best practice to something like this usage?

Comment: Metadata is not merged with the base class. I am not sure what flexibility you can have with the decorators, because of the way Angular inspects them (especially Ivy). You could try `@Component(AbstractList({....}))` where `AbstractList` is a function that generates the options, but I have a strong feeling Angular won't like it.

Comment: Oh you should be able to do `@Component({...abstractList, selector: 'app-my-custom-list})` where `abstractList` is an exported object from the base class file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After [@Rectangular](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1031569/reactgular)'s useful comments I started this way:

In abstract class:

```js
export const componentDecoratorPreset = {
  // selector isn't defined here
  templateUrl: './abstract-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./abstract-list.component.scss']
};

export abstract class AbstractListComponent<T> implements OnInit {
  // ...
}
```

And then in the implementation:

```js
import { AbstractListComponent, componentDecoratorPreset } from 'src/app/components/_absrtact/list/abstract-list.component';

@Component({
  ...componentDecoratorPreset,
  selector: 'app-my-custom-list',
})
```

It's just didn't worked of course because the `templateUrl` was relative and in the implementation the `./abstract-list.component.html` file not exists.

Next step I just tried to use absolute paths in the abstract class like this:

```js
export const componentDecoratorPreset = {
  // selector isn't defined here
  templateUrl: 'src/app/components/_absrtact/list/abstract-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['src/app/components/_absrtact/list/abstract-list.component.scss']
};
```

The official [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/Component#templateurl) say:

> The relative path or absolute URL of a template file...

But the path can't be absolute. After little searching I found [this article](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/08/component-relative-paths-in-angular-2.html) in the topic, and it make sense why the path can't be absolute. But I get an idea from this article:

I created a `abstract-list.component.html.ts` - it's important the extension is `.ts` - with this content:

```js
export default `<div class="container-fluid">...here is the abstract's template...</div>`
```

Then import this template as a variable in the abstract class and export as an object:

```js
import template from './abstract-list.component.html';

export const componentDecoratorPreset = {
  // selector: must be defined in the implementation
  template: template as string,
};
```

Finally in the implementation:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractListComponent, componentDecoratorPreset } from 'src/app/components/_absrtact/list/abstract-list.component';
import { AddressTypeInterface } from 'src/app/models/address/type/address-type.interface';
import { AddressType } from 'src/app/models/address/type/address-type.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-address-type-list',
  ...componentDecoratorPreset
})
export class AddressTypeListComponent extends AbstractListComponent<AddressTypeInterface> implements OnInit {
  constructor() {
    super(AddressType);
  }
}
```